# google play store calling device incompatible, yet compatible in google play console

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-services, google-play-console

I've been trying to test elements of my unity project using google's internal testing within google play console. My device is cited to be compatible yet on my phone i run into the error this phone is not compatible.
[image: device compatible according to console]
[image: device is not compatible with app on play store]

Tried reuploading, clearing google cache, changing compression format, tried from samsung s10 where it did work

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

- You cleared the Google cache, but I am not sure which one exactly. If you haven't cleared the Google Play Services cache and data, try doing that and then restart your phone.
- Your device model, SM-A415F, is not listed on the Google Play Console screenshot.
- Make sure you have uploaded the APK for the correct architecture, arm64-v8a.
- Double-check all the app requirements in the Google Play listing, such as phone storage, screen size, etc.
- If you're not using the latest version of Google Play Services, they update it.
- If none of these steps help, you can contact Google Support at https://support.google.com/googleplay/gethelp?sjid=11667922555128739139-EU